# can't boot fedora 23 livecd on my tablet

Tags: linux, fedora, livecd, tablet

I can get it booting and can see the filling splash. However, my usb drive is attached through the tablet's OTG port which needs `DWC3_XHCI` to be on, which most kernels don't. Can I re-compile the `vmlinuz0` in `/isolinux`? Or where can I get a copy to get it enabled?

**EDIT:** I found [this dwc3.ko](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kmod%28dwc3.ko%29&submit=Search+...&system=Fedora&arch=) may be helpful, but how to load it into the kernel at *grub*? I can't use keyboards after the kernel loads as it's also on that OTG hub.

**EDIT2:** I disabled `rghb` and `quiet` in the boot loader, and found out that I stuck at this:

```
[OK] Reached Target Basic System.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd have to compile your own version of the installation media. The installer used by the Fedora project is [Anaconda](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda) and the source code can be found [on Github](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda). Their wiki contains a detailed [building guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Building) but it doesn't mention specifically how to prepare the installation media.

Another project you may want to look into is [Kickstart](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst), which you can use to prepare customized installation media. Again, no clear method of replacing only the kernel of the default installer.

Comment: Seems like the only thing i need to touch is the kernel, while seems like `anaconda` deals with things more high level. Maybe I can just grab a copy of the media's kernel source and compile it, then replace `/isolinux/vmlinuz0`?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: my only machine is this tablet and it's currently using android, i can run very limited tools (from busybox) on it.